# Getting the init parameters in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, deployment-descriptor, init-parameters

I am new to servlets. I got the `init` parameters in DD within the `init()` method using `getInitParameter`("name"). I tried a lot from within `doGet()` method to access the `init` parameters, but it always returns `null`.

I tried with

`getServletContext().getInitParametr("name")`

and with

`getServletConfig().getInitParametr("name")`

but they all return `null`. Can I get the init parameters in the `doGet()`?

Comment: there's no reason `this.getInitParameter()` returns something else when called from `doGet()` than what it returns when called from `init()`. Maybe you had a typo in your parameter name.

Answer (score 74):

The answer is - **Yes, you can**.

OK, besides the *JB Nizet's* comment here are a few suggestions.

**1)** Have you added your init parameters while the [Web Container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) / [Application Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server) was running?

Quote from ["*Head First Servlets & JSP: Passing the Sun Certified Web Component Developer Exam*"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516681):

> **The servlet init parameters are read only ONCE - when the Container
>   initializes the servlet**. 
>    ...
>   When the Container makes a servlet, it
>   reads the DD and creates the name/value pairs for the ServletConfig.
>   The Container never reads the init parameters again! Once the
>   parameters are in the ServletConfig, **they won’t be read again
>   until/unless you redeploy the servlet**.

**2)** There are two types of *init parameters* available. Another quote from "*Head First Servlets and JSP*" (emphasis mine):

> There are **context init parameters** (defined in `<context-param>` element) and **servlet init parameters** (defined in `<init-param>` element). They are both referred to as *init parameters*, although defined in different elements.
>
> - *Context* init parameters are **available to any** servlet or JSP that are part of the current web app.
> - *Servlet* init parameters are **available to only** the servlet for which the `<init-param>` was configured.
> - *Context* init parameters are defined within the `<web-app>` element.
> - *Servlet* init parameters are defined within the `<servlet>` element **for each specific servlet**.

---

### Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Servlet testing app</display-name>

    <!-- This is a context init parameter -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>email</param-name>
        <param-value>admin@example.com</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Info Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.InfoServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- This is a servlet init parameter -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>name</param-name>
            <param-value>John Doe</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Info Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/ShowInfo.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

- Accessing **context init parameter** in a servlet:
  `getServletContext().getInitParameter(“email”);`
- Accessing **servlet init parameter** in a servlet for which it was
  defined in the [*deployment
  descriptor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_descriptor):
  `getServletConfig().getInitParameter("name");`

An alternative way of getting **servlet init parameter** is using a method defined in the abstract class [*GenericServlet*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getInitParameter-java.lang.String-):
`public String getInitParameter(String name);`
This method is supplied for convenience. It gets the value of the named parameter from the servlet's *ServletConfig* object.

And there is also `Enumeration<String> getInitParameterNames()` method for both [*ServletContext*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) and [*ServletConfig*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html) to get **all** init parameters.

Comment: Bang-on! Great explanation. I was refactoring some code, and this issue started happening. Accidentally replaced a getServletConfig() with getServletContext(), and didn't realize that they have different sets of init-parameters.

Answer (score 9):

if you have overrided the default init() method, make sure that you pass Servlet config parameter to it and also call the super init method . cause if you dont do that , there no way that your code can find your servlet configuration.

here is the code for servlet init() code:

```
   public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    // Rest of your code ...
    }
```

also i noticed that you used Servlet version 3, i am not sure if it supports defining servlet tags, so if the above solution dosen work , try to remove web-app attributes too.