# Java equivalent for C#'s ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[x]

Tags: java

New to Java and I'm trying to find the equivalent for web.config application settings in .NET.

So far I have found examples of something like this:

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:/appSettings.properties");
props.load(fis);
```

However, I know that .NET caches the web.config file and inserting a call to `Configuration.AppSettings[x]` is not expensive. I'm looking for an equivalent solution. So that I can call for Application settings multiple times through out a page load.

**For Example:**

```xml
<link  href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/main.css?ver=" + Configuration.AppSettings["version"]) %>" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I can create a class that can do the equivalent, but i'd hate to reinvent the wheel if there is already something there.

Comment: Create a properties file and load it into your application through ServletContext.

Comment: Word of advice: it doesn't help you to try and make Java behave like .NET; the two platforms have completely different design philosophies. Rather try and find a way to do what you functionally want to achieve within the context of the Java (Enterprise?) platform and forget that .NET exists.

Comment: The Java equivalent for .NET's `Web.config` is `web.xml`, the deployment descriptor for webapps, which is in the WEB-INF directory of your webapp. You can set parameters there which are accessible via the `ServletContext` as Luiggi mentioned.

Comment: @Jesper: Thanks, could you point me to any examples or tutorials? And does it get cached?

Comment: See for example: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafo.html

Comment: Hava a look into **tag libraries** and **EL, expression language**. For something like `<link  href="${resolveUrl('~/css/main.css?ver=' + configuration.appSettings['version'])}" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />` _and better_. Look at message bundle tags (properties) and java beans.

Comment: @Jesper is [this](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/how-to-pass-parameters-to-whole-servlet-application-servletcontext/) what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, that's how you can set parameters in `web.xml` that you can access from your servlets or JSPs.

Comment: @Jesper Create an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java equivalent for .NET's `Web.config` is `web.xml`, the deployment descriptor for Java EE webapps.

In `web.xml` you can set context parameters, that you can access via the class `ServletContext` in your servlets or JSPs. For example:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycompany.myapp.SomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<context-param>
    <param-name>myparam</param-name>
    <param-value>hello</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Inside your JSP:

```
// 'application' is an implicit variable available inside JSPs
// that refers to the ServletContext
String value = application.getInitParameter("myparam");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use init-param in web.xml. I got this from Google Cloud Endpoint's example at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/required_files

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.helloendpoints.Greetings</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Another example from a post at [Getting the init parameters in a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665037/getting-the-init-parameters-in-a-servlet) shows:
Accessing servlet init parameter in a servlet for which it was defined in DD:

```
getServletConfig().getInitParameter("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/
**apache commons configuration is the best choice.**

***Automatic Reloading***
A common issue with properties file is to handle the reloading of the file when it changes.  The sample code is found beneath：

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new 
PropertiesConfiguration("usergui.properties");
config.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());
```

Comment: Please explain why the given URL is the best choice.