# What is the use of <init-param> in web.xml regarding servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

***What is the use of init-param tag? in web.xml reagarding servlet and jsp?***

```
<servlet>  
<servlet-name>sonoojaiswal</servlet-name>  
<jsp-file>/welcome.jsp</jsp-file>  

<init-param>  
<param-name>dname</param-name>  
<param-value>sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</param-value>  
</init-param>  

</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>sonoojaiswal</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can pass parameters to our servlet from the `web.xml` file using init param's. Here's a small example.

### web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>Test</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.Test</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>dname</param-name>
            <param-value>sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

### Servlet:

```
PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
printWriter.println(getServletConfig().getInitParameter("dname"));
```

### Output:

[image]

You will find an excellent answer by *informatik01* on this subject **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665037/getting-the-init-parameters-in-a-servlet/14677792#14677792)**.

Answer (score 3):

You can see that init-param is defined inside a servlet element. This means it is only available to the servlet under declaration and not to other parts of the web application. 
You can use that particular parameter in only this Servlet not in others.
you can access it by ServletConfig object also

```
servletConfig.getInitParameter("dname");
```

Answer (score 1):

They are called Servlet init parameters (defined in  element)

Servlet init parameters are defined within the  element for each specific servlet.

They are specific to each servlet.They are available in the init method of the servlet as arguments. this will be used for initial loading of values in the servlet.