# File upload to server using java

Tags: java, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file to a server.I'm using apache tomcat and java .
Following is my code,

Fileuploadservlet.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

@WebServlet("/UploadServlet")


public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

private boolean isMultipart;
private String filePath;
private int maxFileSize = 1000 * 1024;
private int maxMemSize = 40 * 1024;
private File file ;

public void init( ){
  // Get the file location where it would be stored.
  filePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload"); 
}

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
   doPost(request,response);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

  // Check that we have a file upload request
  isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );

  if( !isMultipart ) {
     out.println("<html>");
     out.println("<head>");
     out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
     out.println("</head>");
     out.println("<body>");
     out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
     out.println("</body>");
     out.println("</html>");
     return;
  }

  DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

  // maximum size that will be stored in memory
  factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);

  // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
  factory.setRepository(new File("C:\\temp"));

  // Create a new file upload handler
  ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

  // maximum file size to be uploaded.
  upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

  try { 
     // Parse the request to get file items.
     List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

     // Process the uploaded file items
     Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

     out.println("<html>");
     out.println("<head>");
     out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
     out.println("</head>");
     out.println("<body>");

     while ( i.hasNext () ) {
        FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
        if ( !fi.isFormField () ) {
           // Get the uploaded file parameters
           String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
           String fileName = fi.getName();
           String contentType = fi.getContentType();
           boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
           long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();

           // Write the file
           if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ) {
              file = new File( filePath + fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
           } else {
              file = new File( filePath + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
           }
           fi.write( file ) ;
           out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName + "<br>");
        }
     }
     out.println("</body>");
     out.println("</html>");
     } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
     }
  }
```

}

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>FileUploadServletExample</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>UploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>    

<context-param> 
  <description>Location to store uploaded file</description> 
  <param-name>file-upload</param-name> 
  <param-value>
     C:\Users\e48265\apache-tomcat-7.0.81\webapps\data\
  </param-value> 
</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>upload.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

upload.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Upload Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
  Select a file to upload: <br />
  <form action = "UploadServlet" method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-
 data">
     <input type = "file" name = "file" size = "50" />
     <br />
     <input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" />
  </form>
 </center>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I'm getting the following output after running upload.jsp file and clicking upload button,
java.io.FileNotFoundException: null\quizlet.txt (The system cannot find the path specified).

Can anyone help me with ?

Note:quizlet.txt is my file that I want to upload.

Comment: `filePath` is null, that is the problem

Comment: I'm new to this.Where should I change the file path?

Comment: You have `filePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload");`. Looks like you didn't set up some initial parameters.

Comment: Where should I setup initial parameters?

Comment: It's your project and your code, you should know. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665037/getting-the-init-parameters-in-a-servlet

Comment: Thank you very much.I got it