# How to get context-params in embedded Jetty WebAppContext?

Tags: java, web-applications, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am running an embedded server using jetty and providing resource base and descriptors to start the server. I have some context-parameters in my web.xml file which I need to read. I have tried searching but couldn't find a way to do that.
Here is my code.

```
static int port = 8081;
static Server server;

public static void start(String[] args) {

        while (!stop) {

            server = new Server(port);

            String wardir = "webapps/war";

            WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
            context.setResourceBase(wardir);
            String webXML = "/WEB-INF/web.xml";
            context.setDescriptor("wardir + webXML");
            context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]{
                new AnnotationConfiguration(), new WebXmlConfiguration(),
                new WebInfConfiguration(), new TagLibConfiguration(),
                new PlusConfiguration(), new MetaInfConfiguration(),
                new FragmentConfiguration(), new EnvConfiguration()});

            context.setContextPath("/");
            context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
            server.setHandler(context);


            try {
            server.start();
            server.dump(System.err);
            server.join();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
}
```

How do I read the context parameters set in web.xml file?

Comment: Use the `ServletContext` as seen in previous question/answer.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665037/getting-the-init-parameters-in-a-servlet